# Teradataml: Remove all temporary tables created by Teradata MLE functions

Tags: python, teradata

In teradataml how should the user remove temporary tables created by Teradata MLE functions?

Answer (score 0):

At the end of a session call remove_context() to trigger the dropping of tables.